# thread synchronization with main()

Tags: c, sockets, pthreads

```
main()
{
    i=9000000000;      // to synchronize thread with while loop
    while(i)i--;      //if i don't use these two lines then my program terminates before thread starts.
    udp_socket();
    fun();
}

udp_socket()
{ 
    // open a udp socket then create thread
    pthread_create(tid1,NULL,fun2,(int *)socket_descriptor2);
}

fun()
{
}

fun2(int socket_descriptor2)
{
    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

1. i opened a UDP socket then create a thread ,inside thread a while loop is continuosly recieving data on the defined ip and port.
2. My thread stop working when main terminates.....
3. i want to execute my thread continuously even when the main() terminates OR my main() also execute continuously without termination .

how can i implement this?

Comment: That program doesn't make sense. `i` what? Nine billion? No prototypes? Please tell me the program compiles without errors or *warnings*. Not to mention the formatting. You *do* know how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: By the way, you might want to search for the and read about *detached threads*, or `pthread_exit`, or just fork a new process.

Comment: Using a while loop for synchronisation is entirely the wrong way to do it (in general). Even if you get it to work at some point it will be highly timing and system dependent and so likely to fail at some other point. You need to do synchronisation with mechanisms designed for that purpose such as semaphore, mutex, pipe, wait, join, etc. Concurrency is a whole computer science topic so if you don't already know the theory then best start with getting that basic understanding before attempting to write multi-threaded applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> i want to execute my thread continuously even when the main() terminates

To do so exit `int main()` by calling `pthread_exit()`:

```
int main(void)
{
  ...

  pthread_exit(NULL); /* This call exits main() and leaves all other thread running. */

  return 0; /* Is never reached, it's just there to silence the compiler. */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want your `main` to terminate too early, make it at least waiting for thread termination. Suppose that you have `tid1` accessible in your main, a simple call to `pthread_join(tid1,NULL)` will let the main thread waits.

Comment: if i use pthread_detach in place of pthread_join,is it fine ??

Comment: No `pthread_detach` will not solve your problem: you need (as I understand) to make your `main` wait for some condition to terminate.

Answer (score 1):

In below example `main` waits for thread to complete (`fun2` to return). `fun2` returns when you enter an integer on `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

void fun() {
  printf("Hello from fun\n");
}

void fun2() {
  int a;
  scanf("%d", &a);
}

pthread_t udp_socket() {
  pthread_t tid;
  pthread_create(&tid,NULL,fun2,NULL);
  return tid;
}

int main() {
  void * ret = NULL;
  pthread_t t = udp_socket();
  fun();
  if(pthread_join(t, &ret)) {             // Waits for thread to terminate
    printf("Some Error Occurred\n");
  }
  else {
    printf("Successfully executed\n");
  }
```

[Here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html) is more information about `pthread_join`.